# Linux sed command is not working when trying to substitute environment variable

Tags: linux, sed, command, environment-variables, string-substitution

I have an environment variable LIB_HOME=/etc/temp
In one of the config files, i'm trying to replace entire line using sed command as follows

```
sed -i '/lib.home=/c\lib.home=$LIB_HOME' myconfig.properties
```

Actual Output   : `lib.home=blablabla` ===> `lib.home=$LIB_HOME`

Expected Output : `lib.home=blablabla` ===> `lib.home=/etc/temp`

Please help

Comment: replace the single quotes `'` with double quotes `"` - you are not allowing the shell to substitute.

Comment: Kabanus, i tried the command as follows == sed -i '/lib.home=/c\lib.home=$LIB_HOME' myconfig.properties == still the output is "lib.home=$LIB_HOME". Please help me with command

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using double quotes?

```
sed -i '/lib.home=/c\lib.home=‘“$LIB_HOME”' myconfig.properties
```

Comment: Yes Vikram. Output is lib.home="$LIB_HOME". But expected output is lib.home=/ect/temp

Comment: With GNU sed: `LIB_HOME="/etc/temp"; sed -Ei 's|(lib.home=).*|\1'"$LIB_HOME"'|' myconfig.properties`

Comment: for me it worked, may be the quote using mobile device are wrong

`# cat > myconfig.properties
lib.home=
# LIB_HOME="/etc/temp"; sed -i '/lib.home=/c\lib.home='"$LIB_HOME" myconfig.properties
# cat myconfig.properties
lib.home=/etc/temp`


`# sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: Thanks Cyrus.. Your suggestion worked for me..

Comment: Thanks Vikram for your valuable suggestion..